# Python PIL glitches when I resize with 'Image.ANTIALIAS'

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

If I resize an image in python using

```
img=img.resize((w,h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

It only gives me the left half of the image. It works fine without antialiasing, but is ugly. Has anyone seen this? Here is a minimal working(?) example that works/fails with any tif I've tried:

```
import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img=Image.open("test.tif")
img=img.resize((300,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
imgm=np.asarray(img.getdata()).reshape(img.size[1],img.size[0])
imgm=np.log10(imgm)

imgview=plt.imshow(imgm)
```

Edit: Repeating this, the right side of the image is different each time, though it often contains a glitched portion of the left side of the original image.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work ok for me with [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) using [MARBLES.TIF](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/sample/):

```
from PIL import Image

img=Image.open("MARBLES.TIF")
img=img.resize((300,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)

img.show()
```

Adding:

```
img.save("test.png")
```

I get:

[image: test.png]